# Is this SSO design secure?

Tags: sso

We're working on an SSO implementation that would be used accross domains.  I realize there are proven working models out there like CAS for this but I'm toying with a different approach and I want to get feedback from you all here to see if this is secure or not.  The basic premise is that we don't want to use redirects if we don't have to and we want the product sites to be able to style their own login pages. This targets IE8+ and modern FF and webkit only. So, without further ado the implementation:

1. Client browses to product site A.com.  They don't have a session cookie for a.com so the site initiates the parent auth script.
2. The parent script builds an iframe that loads a page from the auth server on auth.com. Auth.com validates the request based on the referer header and if the referer isnt trusted then responds with x-frame-options:DENY and/or a frame busting redirect.
3. The script on this page (the framed script) does an ajax request to auth.com's server asking for an SSO 1 time token (1TT).
4. The client doesn't have an auth.com cookie so this is rejected, and the iframe script tells the parent script to build an auth form using window.postMessage (and the parent script validates the origin) to communicate since it is cross domain.
5. The user enters their credentials, and hits submit.
6. The credentials get passed from the parent script to the framed script via postMessage again, and the framed script uses them to login to auth.com, receiving both an auth.com cookie and a 1TT.
7. The 1TT is passed back to the parent script.
8. The parent script passes the 1TT to A.com's server.
9. A.com uses the 1TT to get the user info from auth.com's server via a private internal API, and auth.com invalidates the 1TT so it can't be used again.
10. A.com returns a session cookie for A.com to the client, and now the client goes about its business on A.com.
11. Then the client browses to B.com, but again has no session cookie for B.com.  The parent script is executed again, which creates an iframe again pointing to auth.com. The iframe script requests a 1TT from auth.com, and since it has a session cookie for auth.com this time it gets one.
12. The 1TT is passed from the iframe script to the parent script to B.com's server which uses it to get the user from auth.com and issue a session cookie for B.com.

My main concern is at step 2. Is this a solid way to prevent malicious framing?  What other security vulnerabilities is this susceptible to?

Edit: All sites and scripts will be loaded HTTPS.

Comment: Actually, this is surprisingly close to stack exchanges authentication. I just need to switch to localStorage for auth.com's session info.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274

Comment: For starters, the referrer header can easily be forged, you can not rely on it for security.

Comment: The vulnerability though is that faking the `referer` header logs you into a site you would otherwise have access to; not sure if it's that big a deal (esp. since I assume you issue tokens per-site)

Comment: Jeff, I thought that at first too but it turns out to not be as true as you might think.  I can forge my own referer header with various browser plugins but I can't forge someone else's referer header in a CSRF or even an XSS attack so it turns out to actually be secure.  If you have evidence otherwise, I'd love to see implementation or a link.

Comment: As with all security related stuff, please don't roll your own. As someone who has spent most of his life writing SSO-related code (that may not be saying much), please don't try to do this on your own. Rely on existing protocols.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information in your list (as hard as that is to believe, with 12 steps and all) to properly answer, but as you mentioned in your comment above - this is pretty close to the StackExchange model.

With that in mind; have you considered running your own [OpenID Provider](http://openid.net/add-openid/become-a-provider/)? The [protocol spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#anchor2) looks pretty close to what you're after. This is also a well-tested model, so a lot of the concerns have already been well-solved. [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) may be suitable, but it's designed around limited access tokens - don't know enough about what you're doing to say which is more appropriate.

Coming back to your model - what you've specified looks ok, though as written there's a mix of 'model' stuff and 'implementation' stuff that makes it a bit tricky to analyse. You're relying on the referrer, but it looks like in this scenario, faking the referrer will only log a client in to a different site they would have access to anyway. You are depending on `referer` though - maybe just load the frame with a GET request including the referrer?

You're also relying on the ability to pass info back and forth between frames; you may want to consider using an interim page on auth.com instead (i.e. forward user to auth.com, if user already logged in there, POST back to https://B.com with 1TT). Using iframes complicates things (What if you're already in a frame? You're relying on the browser here to 'break out' successfully - could this be subverted by messing with the DOM?). You *may* be able to make this secure, but it's a complicating factor - and the enemy of good security tends to be overly-complicated schemes.

Comment: OpenID and OAuth both rely on redirects which is what I want to avoid.  

I'm going to have to think about a frame within a frame (within a frame within a frame) possiblity but I think all of that can be pretty easily defeated with x-frame-options:DENY.  

Loading the frame would be a GET request, yes, which includes the referer unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I mean add it to your query string so you're not relying on the browser to send it (in the case where a user has referers turned off, or you're requesting across domains and one is https). x-frame-options:DENY relies on the browser also doing the right thing - there's no reason an attacker can't just ignore it.

Comment: In what scenario would an attacker be able to ignore x-frame-options in order to hijack someone's session?  As for turning off the referer, I'm of the opinion that you have to be an advanced user to do that so telling such a user that they need to allow referer for authentication doesn't really bother me.  But ideally I'll setup a local login to site A.com without SSO in addition.

Comment: In any scenario where they're making an HTTP request, they can choose to ignore it, they can instruct users to turn it off, etc. (don't underestimate the social engineering aspect) - but just because it's hard to articulate a precise attack doesn't mean that it's hard to exploit. (Also, checking the referer and checking the query string are about as hard as each other - why not just make it work when it's turned off? The principle here is *don't trust the client*, build your site with that assumption and you'll automatically make it harder to attack.)

Comment: Well, as for the query string, a malicious framer can write any query string they like, whereas forging the referer is much harder.  They can only forge a referer for a domain they control.
I agree that its worth while to make it be able to login to the local site directly when the referer is missing, or as the stack exchange implementation outlines, any time anything seems off.

Comment: That's really not true - forging the referer is easy, so is forging the query string, but neither matter; because it's not that big a risk to authenticate a user against a service they have access to - just make the token site specific.

Comment: Fair point.  But as a matter of academic curiosity, how can one forge the referer of someone else's browser?

Comment: A simple method is to find a site that has an open redirect (or set one up yourself; http://somesite.com/?redirectto=auth.com) and run a DNS poisoning attack of some sort to make somesite look like your site.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.  But if Oscar can manage DNS poisoning then I think Alice and Bob have quite a bit more to worry about.

Comment: We're getting way off topic; maybe worth a second question if you want detailed answers. The quick answer is: 'DNS Poisononing is easier than you think, public wifi plus a [cheap device](http://hak5.org/store/wifi-pineapple) - and cache entries can outlive your connection to a compromised network.'

Comment: Huh. Yeah you're right, that's pretty easy. Interesting.

Comment: So in order for that to work for this, Oscar would have to dns cache poison hax.com to be A.com, but since auth.com is on https, then the referer won't come through unless Oscar can also get a cert for A.com, which I hope is harder than DNS cache poisoning. :)

Answer (score 1):

This SSO Design has a number of technical limitation that make it impossible to implement.  There are security concerns with this design.

The **worst** vulnerability that this design implements is [OWASP A9-Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  SSL must be used to protect all authentication information, therefore if you spill an authentication cookie over HTTP a session could be hijacked.  So if a user on a wifi network were to authenticate using this SSO Design,  they could have their account hacked with a tool like [firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep/).

**#2 is not possible:**
The originating site `A.com` must load the authentication iframe using an HTTPS page. However,  by doing this,  the `referer` header element will be missing and there is no way to verify where the request is originating from. [Mozilla's Origin Header Proposal](http://people.mozilla.org/~bsterne/content-security-policy/origin-header-proposal.html) is trying to fix this problem,  but its not supported by all browsers.  OAuth uses a [Signed Callback URL](http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238555/Signed%20Callback%20URLs) to insure that a browser is being authenticated to a trusted domain.

For #9, instead of sharing user data with "private internal API",  try using a public standard like OAuth.  In fact what you have described sounds a lot like **[3-legged OAuth](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2011/06/what-is-2-legged-oauth.html)**.  OAuth is probably how you authenticated to http://security.stackexchange.com to ask this question,  and it has proven to be secure.

Comment: HTTPS can send `referer` if going to another HTTPS site. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.1.3

Comment: @Bob Watson this does not hold for cross-domain requests.  That would be information leakage.  Some CSRF exploits use this to obscure their origin,  try it.

Comment: *can* is the operative. Most browsers *don't*, but you may not want to rely on that, since they meet the spec if they *do*. Not that that helps the questioner.

Comment: @Bob Watson Let me know of a browser that does this.  I would be happy to submit the information leakage vulnerability to their bug tracker.

Comment: Regardless; I'm not sure if his model requires HTTPS as long as auth.com submits via HTTPS (you could also include the referring site in a GET string) as messing with the `referer` data will only log you into sites the authenticator has access to *anyway*. And the 'internal API' in this scenario may be something like 'request to a backend db server'. You will have to manage the 'stealing the token in transit' risk if HTTP is a requirement, but there's detail missing to make the determination.

Comment: I was wrong above; most browsers *do* send referer with https http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendSecureXSiteReferrer / https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=sendSecureXSiteReferrer - in fact, it was removed and [added back in](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141641)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that everything would be HTTPS. I need to verify which browsers do and don't send a referer header between https; maybe I'll do that this weekend.

Comment: @rbrc what advantage does this proposed SSO Design have over 3-legged OAuth?

Comment: It allows a.com b.com et al to skin their own login pages without having to edit code on auth.com and it removes redirects from the process, which are something of a poor user experience and can be particularly slow on mobile.  I'm coding this up this weekend so we'll see if it's any more mobile friendly, I honestly doubt it but we'll see.

Comment: @rbrc I don't think that is a good reason.  OAuth is popular for a reason,  and it is designed by people who have a better understanding of secuirty.

Comment: OAuth is popular because it was the best option available at the time. The main technology that has been introduced that wasn't available previously is localStorage which is needed to store session data for auth.com. As I mentioned earlier, this is essentially the exact same thing as what stackexchange uses (except they curiously don't use ssl), so I'm not actually breaking new ground, and I find it interesting that as of yet no one in this thread has come up with a significant problem with this design.

Comment: @rbrc yes the lack of a signed callback url is a significant mistake.   Also this is hardly a technical document,  this is just a list of features... that is impossible to impalement.  Also OAuth is pretty bad ass and thats why it is so popular.  Its a great design!

Comment: @rbrc also StackOverflow contains known vulnerabilities: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft